# 500 Internal Server error after SP setup

Tags: 2016, central-administration, configuration-wizard

I just created a new farm using SP 2016 single server role, I tried to open the central admin, but am getting "This site can’t be reached" in Chrome and "Runtime Error" in IE, when I saw the trace logs, I could see this:

**ModuleName**
AspNetInitializationExceptionModule

**Notification**
BEGIN_REQUEST

**HttpStatus**
500

**HttpReason**
Internal Server Error

**HttpSubStatus**
0

**ErrorCode**
The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)

I am not sure what's going on. It's windows server 2016, SQL server 2016, I installed everything in the same server. Is this a known issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your CA application pool started?

Comment: yes it is started.